# For $n \geq 3$ be an integer, consider $S=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1 \\ (i,n)=1}}^n i$, then $n \mid S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer. Consider $S=\sum\limits_{\substack{i=1 \\ (i,n)=1}}^n i$. I want to show that $n \mid S$.

How do I approach? I am not sure if this can be proved in general, I only checked for some particular values of $n$. I need help to prove it or a counter example to disprove it.

Comment: note:  if $(i,n)=1$, then $(n-i,n)=1$

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ and $i$, are coprime, $n$, and $n-i$ are coprime too.

For every term $i$ in the sum, there will be the term $n-i$ too, so that the sum will be a multiple of $n$.

Further note: You can see that the sum will be equal to $\dfrac{\varphi(n)}{2}\cdot{n}$, because there are $\varphi(n)$ terms in the sum, and $\varphi(n)/2$ pairs that add up to $n$.

Further explanation: In the situation where $n-i = i$, we get $n = 2i$, which means that $i$ isn't coprime with $n$.

Comment: I think you should mention the case where $i=n-i$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. $i$ won't be coprime with $n$ in that case, but it's worth to mention.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their [assessed homework or exam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33557/10513), so giving them the complete answer is unfair to the rest of their class.